# Determine the function to be injective when $f: A\to N$, where $A=\{1,4,3\}$ and $f(x)=x^{2}$.

Tags: functions

I claimed the function is injective since the elements in domain  maps uniquely to elements in the codomain when plug into $f(x)=x^{2}$ .

which gives $\{1,16,9\}$ where $\{1,16,9\}$ is found in the codomain $N$.

I'm I correct?

Comment: Absolutely correct.

Answer (score 1):

That is correct.

By the definition $f:A\to N$ is injective if for all  $a,b\in A$ such that $a\neq b$, we have that $f(a)\neq f(b)$.

In this case we simply need to check a few cases: 
$$1\neq 4 \Rightarrow f(1)=1\neq 16= f(4)$$
$$4\neq 3 \Rightarrow f(4)=16\neq 9=f(3)$$ 
$$3\neq 1 \Rightarrow f(3)=9\neq 1 =f(1)$$

Thus $f$ satisfies the definition of an injective function.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you are correct. Something that would not be injective would be if your domain was $\{-1,1,2,4\}$ because both $1$ and $-1$ map to $1$ but your domain is entirely positively so the function is injective.

Answer (score 0):

Correct. For some $x_1,x_2 \in A$, injectivity means $f(x_1)=f(x_2)$ if and only if $x_1=x_2$. If $x_1 \neq x_2$, but $f(x_1)=f(x_2)$, $f(x)$ is not injective. Some extra questions for you: is $f(x)$ surjective ? bijective ?

Comment: I think Surjective=yes since it will be yes for injective and surjective then yes for surjective.

Comment: Indeed it is surjective. Did you mean to say if yes for injective and surjective, then yes for bijective ?

Comment: I think of it that way.

Comment: Bijective means the function is BOTH injective and surjective.  $f(x)$ here is injective, and it is surjective, so it is bijective.  If you have any more questions, please don't hesitate to ask.

Comment: Injectivity isn't generally defined as you did with "if and only if", just "If $f(x_1)=f(x_2) $ then $ x_1=x_2$". The other direction is satisfied by all well-defined functions and doesn't need to be checked.

Comment: if f:R$\to$R and $f(x)=x^{2}$ is it injective? i think it is not since $f(-1)^{2}$=1 and $f(1)^{2}$=1

Comment: @surdz That's right. If we extend the domain and range to $\mathbb{R}$ then $f(x)=x^2$ is not injective anymore. Your example is right.

Comment: @surdz If by the codomain $N$ you mean the natural numbers $\mathbb{N}$, then $f:A\to \mathbb{N}$ where $f(x)=x^2$ is NOT surjective! For example take $2\in \mathbb{N}$, there is no element $x \in A$ such that $f(x)=2$.

Comment: And as it is not surjective it is not bijective either...

Comment: You are right, sorry, I erroneously thought $N$ was just the set {1,16,9} sorry !

Comment: Yes in that case it would be! ;)